# ddrescue: Unaligned read error. Is sector size correct?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue, gdisk

I'm trying to use GNU `ddrescue` to recover raw data from a failing SSD. System is Debian Stretch.

---

Thus far, I have this info out of it:

**`dmesg`**

```
[Sun Sep  8 15:04:20 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB/224 GiB)
[Sun Sep  8 15:04:20 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[Sun Sep  8 15:04:20 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Sun Sep  8 15:04:20 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Sun Sep  8 15:04:51 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[Sun Sep  8 15:06:43 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Sep  8 15:06:43 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[Sun Sep  8 15:06:44 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Sep  8 15:06:44 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#21 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 da 00 00 00 00 00 4f 00 c2 00 b0 00
[Sun Sep  8 15:09:49 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[Sun Sep  8 15:09:49 2019] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[Sun Sep  8 15:09:49 2019] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0
...
```

---

### Capacity

so, we have the capacity 240057409536 sectors

as initially confirmed by `fdisk` (not accessible anymore with it):

**468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB / 224 GiB)**

---

### What I've tried:

- **`fdisk`**

  First time I ran this tool, it outputted some valuable info, shown above. Second call:

  ```
  # fdisk /dev/sdd

  Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
  Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
  Be careful before using the write command.

  fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdd: No such file or directory
  ```

  Pretty much the same error I get in `sfdisk`, or `testdisk` now.
- **`ls`**

  ```
  brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 Sep  8 16:40 /dev/sdd
  ```

  So, the device is still there.
- **math**

  > `468862128` clusters * `512` sector-size = `240057409536` sectors initially detected by `dmesg`
- **`gdisk`**

  ```
  GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

  Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
  Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
  Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
  Partition table scan:
    MBR: MBR only
    BSD: not present
    APM: not present
    GPT: not present

  ***************************************************************
  Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
  in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
  typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
  to GPT format!
  ***************************************************************

  Command (? for help): p

  Disk /dev/sdd: 0 sectors, 0 bytes
  Model: SATAFIRM   S11  
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
  Disk identifier (GUID): B93E2FDE-39F0-4015-AEC9-96A76520F547
  Partition table holds up to 128 entries
  Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
  First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 18446744073709551582
  Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
  Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

  Command (? for help): x

  Expert command (? for help): o

  Disk size is 0 sectors (0 bytes)
  MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
  MBR partitions:

  Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
     1                     1   4294967295   primary     0xEE
  ```
- **GNU `ddrescue`**

  my test run:

  ```
  ddrescue -d -f -r3 -R --sector-size=512 --size=240057409536  /dev/sdd /dev/null
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  GNU ddrescue 1.23
  Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
       ipos:  240057 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
       opos:  240057 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
  non-tried:  240057 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
    rescued:        0 B,   bad areas:        0,        run time:          0s
  pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:        0,  remaining time:         n/a
                                time since last successful read:         n/a
  Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (backwards)
  Unaligned read error. Is sector size correct?
  ```

---

Here I just don't know what to do next.

---

I welcome any and all suggestions.

---

PS: There are / were Windows 10 partitions. (User doesn't know if upgraded from non-EFI.)

---

**`gdisk`** #2 right after boot time it **shows up proper size**:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 468862128 sectors, 223.6 GiB
Model: SATAFIRM   S11  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 476B6FD3-31DC-448B-834A-1E7F4ED18673
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 468862094
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 468862061 sectors (223.6 GiB)
```

I don't know how or why this state vanishes after a minute or a few.

Comment: Most devices have larger than 512 byte sectors nowadays; 512 byte is emulated (logical) sector size, but physical sector may be 4096 (4K) or even larger and if one of them is bad, all emulated 512 byte sectors in that range will be bad too. Thus ddrescue should be given the physical sector (page) size.

Comment: @frostschutz Tried 4096, I tried every possibility I could think of. This baby is broken... I'm sending it today to data recovery center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not notice the importance of the drive's name:

> **SATAFIRM S11**

---

After a bit of searching, it turned out there might be a way of restoring the SSD drive, but probably not the data.

> The program is designed to restore the health of disks on the Phison 3111 (S11) controller, for example, Smartbuy Revival2, Kingston A400, which, due to some problems, went into protective mode.

+

> **Data**, in the event of a successful recovery, is **destroyed**.

---

[Source: Tom's Hardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/kingston-satafirm-s11-fix.3489081/).