# How can I retrieve data from a HDD that couldn't finish os reinstall?

Tags: disk, data-recovery, ssd, testdisk

My sister asked me to fix her laptop that couldn't recognise some of the peripheries including the network cards. She hasn't used it for almost a year. First (almost half a year ago) I asked her to make a backup of all her files, but she obviously forgot that and now was in a hurry. So I started the laptop, it booted just fine. Date and time was totally nonsense, couldn't connect to any network, couldn't update drivers manually, so I decided to just reinstall the os. It had Windows 10 pre-installed.
The reinstallation started just fine, but around 38% it suddenly got the blue screen of death. After that it wouldn't start, claiming there was no valid boot info on any of the hard drives.

At home I first tried using an external Win10 image, but it couldn't recognise the HDD at all.
I then tried using Ubuntu ran from a USB stick. Gparted keeps saying that it encounters an output/input error while trying to do anything on that HDD.
I since installed Ubuntu onto an external drive, because I had enough having to re-install and re-configure everything all the time; that is sdb with all the partitions. I was paying extra attention not to do anything with the HDD during the process.

lsblk lists the HDD with no partitions, but it's at least there (sda).

```
$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0   7:0    0  63,5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop1   7:1    0  63,4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop2   7:2    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop3   7:3    0  73,9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop4   7:4    0  73,9M  1 loop /snap/core22/864
loop5   7:5    0 237,2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2987
loop6   7:6    0 349,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop7   7:7    0 485,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop8   7:8    0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop9   7:9    0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10
        7:10   0  12,3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop11
        7:11   0  53,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop12
        7:12   0  40,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
loop13
        7:13   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
sda     8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
sdb     8:16   0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1
│       8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2
│       8:18   0   205G  0 part /media/oriba/69895ea3-aa89-4618-ab95-a7bd361f9df6
└─sdb3
        8:19   0  92,6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                /
sr0    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

fdisk now returned this:

```
    $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?
Disk /dev/sda: 223,57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: SATAFIRM   S11  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

That's all; no identifier, no label, no partitions.

However, after trying testdisk and photorec (both finding zero files using the smallest sector size) it usually disappears from there as well: first it appears as a disk with 0 size, then it completely disappears until I shut down the laptop and start it again.
Here's testdisk:
Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 240 GB / 223 GiB - SATAFIRM   S11
Before selecting Quick Search:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 240 GB / 223 GiB - CHS 29185 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
```

After searching, testdisk returns nothing, so I go to deep search, which also returns an empty list, I only see the headers: Partition, Start, End and Size in sectors.

However, if I now type lsblk, it lists sda as size 0:

```
sda     8:0    0     0B  0 disk
```

fdisk doesn't list it anymore, until I reboot.

I never tried to write anything onto that HDD, nor did I try to format it.

Is there anything else I can do or is the hardware malfunctioning? Also, did I mess it up anywhere (apart from not making a backup)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ddrescue: Unaligned read error. Is sector size correct?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539651/ddrescue-unaligned-read-error-is-sector-size-correct)

Comment: Note the `SATAFIRM S11` disk name.